# How to add bullet in comment using Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to add bullet in second line.

```
Public Sub AddComment()
  Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range
  With Selection
    .Font.Bold = True
    .TypeText "Test Bold: Bold Text"
    .TypeText "This text has bullet" & vbNewLine
    .TypeText "This is simple text"
  End With 
End Sub
```

Above code add Font.Bold style in first line. I want to add bullet in second line only. In the third line, there should not have bullet.
Can anybody please suggest me?

Comment: Do you want add a bullet character ( • )? If so, what's stopping you? What does it look like now, and how do you want it to look? (See [mcve])

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer But how can I add symbol here? It may be simple but I don't know how. Please suggest

Comment: Well the simplest solution would be to copy the one I just left in the comment and paste it into your string. Alternatively take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144053/how-to-represent-unicode-chr-code-in-vb-net-string-literal)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer :( I am not getting what do you want to say. I am asking programmatically. How can type symbol in codding?

Comment: Replace `"This text has bullet"` with `"• This text has bullet"`

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Ok. I got your point. Let me try.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer How can I add specific type of symbol? Copy paste that symbol? Let me know about version support of this if you have idea about it. It should Support Office 2010, 2013, 2016, Mac 2011, Mac 2016.

Comment: Look at the link in my second comment. As for version support: Can't say for sure, but Microsoft has been using UTF for ages and it would be strange if it didn't work.